# How to find the lowest and biggest value in a maximum distance between points (SQL)

Tags: postgresql

Currently, I have a PostgreSQL database (and a SQL Server database with almost the same structure), with some data, like example below:

```
+----+---------+-----+
| ID | Name    | Val |
+----+---------+-----+
| 01 | Point A |   0 |
| 02 | Point B | 050 |
| 03 | Point C | 075 |
| 04 | Point D | 100 |
| 05 | Point E | 200 |
| 06 | Point F | 220 |
| 07 | Point G | 310 |
| 08 | Point H | 350 |
| 09 | Point I | 420 |
| 10 | Point J | 550 |
+----+---------+-----+

ID = PK (auto increment);
Name = unique;
Val = unique;
```

Now, suppose I have only **`Point F (220)`**, and I wanna to find the lowest value and biggest value with a maximum distance less than 100 between the data.

So, my result must return:

- Lowest: **Point E (200)**
- Biggest: **Point I (420)**

Step by step explanation (and because english is not my primary language):

- Looking for lowest value:

  ```
  Initial value = Point F (220);
  Look for the lower closest value of Point F (220): Point E (200);
  200(E) < 220(F) = True; 220(F) - 200(E) < 100 = True;
  Lowest value until now = Point E (200)

  Repeat

  Look for the lower closest value of Point E (200): Point D (100);
  100(D) < 200(E) = True; 200(E) - 100(D) < 100 = False;
  Lowest value = Point E (200); Break;
  ```
- Looking fot the biggest value:

  ```
  Initial value = Point F (220);
  Look for the biggest closest value of Point F (220): Point G (310);
  310(G) > 220(F) = True; 310(G) - 220(F) < 100 = True;
  Biggest value until now = Point G (310)

  Repeat

  Look for the biggest closest value of Point G (310): Point H (350);
  350(H) > 310(G) = True; 350(H) - 310(G) < 100 = True;
  Biggest value until now = Point H (350)

  Repeat

  Look for the biggest closest value of Point H (350): Point I (420);
  420(I) > 350(H) = True; 420(I) - 350(H) < 100 = True;
  Biggest value until now = Point I (420)

  Repeat

  Look for the biggest closest value of Point I (420): Point J (550);
  550(J) > 420(I) = True; 550(J) - 420(I) < 100 = False;
  Biggest value Point I (420); Break;
  ```

Comment: How can you identify your "initial value"? Do you have its value (`Val`, i.e. `220` in your example), its `ID` (`06` in your example) or its name (OFC, only if its unique)?

Comment: The `ID` it's a auto increment number. `Val` is unique, and `name` is unique too! I only have the `ID` initially.

Comment: From your comment on the deleted answer (*t's not a interval less than 100 between the point F and min and max! it's between the previous and next point*) it seems to me that this is a special [tag:gaps-and-islands] problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using [Windows Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) and some working.

In a step by step fashion, you would start by having one table (let's call it `point_and_prev_next`) defined by this select:

```
SELECT
    id, name, val, 
    lag(val) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS prev_val, 
    lead(val) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS next_val
FROM
    points
```

which produces:

```
| id |    name | val | prev_val | next_val |
|----|---------|-----|----------|----------|
|  1 | Point A |   0 |   (null) |       50 |
|  2 | Point B |  50 |        0 |       75 |
|  3 | Point C |  75 |       50 |      100 |
|  4 | Point D | 100 |       75 |      200 |
|  5 | Point E | 200 |      100 |      220 |
|  6 | Point F | 220 |      200 |      310 |
|  7 | Point G | 310 |      220 |      350 |
|  8 | Point H | 350 |      310 |      420 |
|  9 | Point I | 420 |      350 |      550 |
| 10 | Point J | 550 |      420 |   (null) |
```

The [`lag` and `lead`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) window functions serve to get the previous and next values from the table (sorted by id, and not partitioned by anything).

Next, we make a second table `point_and_dist_prev_next` which uses `val`, `prev_val` and `next_val`, to compute distance to previous point and distance to next point. This would be computed with the following SELECT:

```
SELECT
    id, name, val, (val-prev_val) AS dist_to_prev, (next_val-val) AS dist_to_next
FROM
    point_and_prev_next
```

This is what you get after executing it:

```
| id |    name | val | dist_to_prev | dist_to_next |
|----|---------|-----|--------------|--------------|
|  1 | Point A |   0 |       (null) |           50 |
|  2 | Point B |  50 |           50 |           25 |
|  3 | Point C |  75 |           25 |           25 |
|  4 | Point D | 100 |           25 |          100 |
|  5 | Point E | 200 |          100 |           20 |
|  6 | Point F | 220 |           20 |           90 |
|  7 | Point G | 310 |           90 |           40 |
|  8 | Point H | 350 |           40 |           70 |
|  9 | Point I | 420 |           70 |          130 |
| 10 | Point J | 550 |          130 |       (null) |
```

And, at this point, (and starting with point "F"), we can get the first "wrong point up" (the first that fails the "distance to previous" < 100) by means of the following query:

```
SELECT
      max(id) AS first_wrong_up
FROM
    point_and_dist_prev_next
WHERE
    dist_to_prev >= 100
    AND id <= 6     -- 6 = Point F
```

This just looks for the point closest to our reference one ("F") which FAILS to have a distance with the previous one < 100.

The result is:

```
| first_wrong_up |
|----------------|
|              5 |
```

The first "wrong point" going down is computed in an equivalent manner.

All these queries can be put together using [Common Table Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html), also called `WITH` queries, and you get:

```
WITH point_and_dist_prev_next AS
(
    SELECT
        id, name, val, 
        val - lag(val) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS dist_to_prev, 
        lead(val) OVER(ORDER BY id)- val AS dist_to_next
    FROM
        points 
),
first_wrong_up AS
(
SELECT
    max(id) AS first_wrong_up
FROM
    point_and_dist_prev_next
WHERE
    dist_to_prev >= 100
    AND id <= 6     -- 6 = Point F
),
first_wrong_down AS
(
SELECT
    min(id) AS first_wrong_down
FROM
    point_and_dist_prev_next
WHERE
    dist_to_next >= 100
    AND id >= 6     -- 6 = Point F
)
SELECT
    (SELECT name AS "lowest value"
       FROM first_wrong_up
       JOIN points ON id = first_wrong_up),
    (SELECT name AS "biggest value"
       FROM first_wrong_down
       JOIN points ON id = first_wrong_down) ;
```

Which provides the following result:

```
| lowest value | biggest value |
|--------------|---------------|
|      Point E |       Point I |
```

You can check it at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/14cd4/5/0).

---

NOTE: It is assumed that the `id` column is always increasing. If it were not, the `val` column would have to be used instead (assuming, obviously, that it always keeps growing).

Comment: tks! i not tested yet (and SQLFiddle is not working right now)! but I liked the explanation in 'step by step fashion' :D

Comment: There's a "bug" in this SQL. If, instead of searching "lowest and biggest value" of Point F, I search the lower and bigger value of Point A, B, C or D, the lowest value will be NULL. The same things happens if I search the biggest value of Point J.

Comment: To correct this "bug", I just changed, in `WHERE` conditions to: `(dist_to_prev >= 100 OR dist_to_prev IS NULL)` AND `(dist_to_next >= 100 OR dist_to_next IS NULL)`.